# hi i want to build a little app game called "sink ships"?

Tags: javascript

hi im a newbie and im currently trying to build an app called sink ships.
I already drew the the circles with a css property and the tanks which look like this <------00000 are also moving with a with javascript I used for that the window.addEventlistener and giving each movement a property case going left right up down. Now I want the circle which symbolices the tanks to move down and up and up again and disappearing when I the bazooka touched the circle (tank) my code looking like this:

```js
let circle = document.getElementById(".circle");
let moveBy = 10;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  circle.style.position = "absolute";
  circle.style.left = 0;
  circle.style.top = 0;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
  }
});

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align-last: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  ast: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: rgb(177, 133, 133)">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <div id=".circle">&lt;------000</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now my question could someone help me with a code that could make my circle move up and down I already copied a code from the internet maybe it could help with the first steps

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague to me. I interpret it to mean that you want the large black circle to move up and down, the ASCII art to move with the keyboard, and if the front of the ASCII art touches the big circle, the big circle disappears.

Traditionally, one would write a game for the browser using a canvas object. In your code you have some content that is trying to use a canvas, but since you do not declare a canvas or create a canvas element in javascript, the canvas code is throwing exceptions. My recommendation would be stop using html elements and move to a canvas. However, to keep the answer as close to the origin code as possible, I'll provide some code that uses the original HTML elements followed by a canvas implementation.

### Element-base solution

If you want to build the game using just html elements, you would need to make the following changes to your script:

```
// var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
// var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// var x = canvas.width/2;
// var y = canvas.height-30;
let x = 100;
let y = 100;
let ticks = 0;
var dx = 2;
var dy = 100;
let bigCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0];

// ctx.beginPath();
function drawBall() {
  // ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
  // ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  // ctx.fill();
  // ctx.closePath();
}

function styleStringToNumber(string) {
  return +(string.substring(0, string.length - 2));
}

function draw() {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // drawBall();
  ticks++;
  animatedY = Math.cos(ticks / 100) * 100 + dy;
  bigCircle.style.top = animatedY;

  let circleBoundary = document.getElementById(".circle").getBoundingClientRect();
  let tip = { x: circleBoundary.left, y: (circleBoundary.top + circleBoundary.bottom) / 2 }
  let distance = Math.sqrt((styleStringToNumber(bigCircle.style.top) + 50 - tip.y) ** 2 + (styleStringToNumber(bigCircle.style.left) + 50 - tip.x) ** 2)
  if (distance < 50)
    bigCircle.style.visibility = "hidden"
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

You also have some ill-formatted code in you css. You can resolve the issues to removing the end of the last line so it only reads "align-items: center;" and by appending a final closing curly brace.

### Description

1. Lines that have to do with a canvas have been commented out
2. We get a reference to the big circle by querying for a list of elements with the class circle and grabbing the first one in the list.
3. We add a function "styleStringToNumber" that will take the positional data from the big circle's style and convert it from a string with a trailing "px" to a number.
4. Move the big circle up and down with time. There are many ways to do this. I chose to use a simple trigonometric function since it eases in and out of it's vertical movement.
5. Get the boundary of the element referenced by circle
6. Use the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance from the center of the big circle and the left side of the 'circle' bounding box.
7. If the distance is less than the radius of the big circle, then change the visibility to hidden.

### Using a Canvas

If you were to convert to using a canvas, you could reproduce this behavior this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onkeyup='keyup(event)'>
  <canvas id="canv" width=640 height=480></canvas>
  <script>
    let ctx = document.querySelector("#canv").getContext("2d")
    let asciiPosition = { x: 0, y: 10 }
    let circlePosition = { x: 0, y: 0 }
    let ticks = 0;
    let showBigCircle = true;

    function main() {
      //update and draw every 10ms
      setInterval(update, 10)
    }

    //Change the state of the game
    function update() {
      ticks++

      circlePosition.y = Math.cos(ticks / 100) * 100 + 100;

      //Check if they are in collision
      let distance = Math.sqrt((asciiPosition.x - (circlePosition.x + 50))**2 + (asciiPosition.y - (circlePosition.y + 50))**2)
      if(distance < 50) 
      showBigCircle = false;

      draw();
    }

    //Draw the game
    function draw() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "lightgreen";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

      ctx.fillStyle = "black"
      ctx.fillText("<------000", asciiPosition.x, asciiPosition.y)

      if (showBigCircle) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circlePosition.x + 50, circlePosition.y + 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
      }

    }

    //Respondto keyboard events
    function keyup(e) {
      let jump = 10;
      switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
          asciiPosition.x -= jump;
          break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
          asciiPosition.x += jump;
          break;
        case 'ArrowUp':
          asciiPosition.y -= jump;
          break;
        case 'ArrowDown':
          asciiPosition.y += jump;
          break;
      }
    }

    //Start the game loop
    main();

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```